# Updating public fields of Rust structs which have private fields

Tags: struct, rust

I have a struct `Foo` which represents an external serialization format. `Foo` has dozens of fields, and more are added all the time. Happily, all new fields are guaranteed to have sensible default values.

Rust has a nice syntax for creating a struct using default values and then updating a few selected values:

```
Foo {
  bar: true,
  ..Default::default()
}
```

Similarly, we can represent the idea of "this struct may have more fields in a future version" using a private field of type `PhantomData`.

But if we combine these two idioms, we get an error:

```
use std::default::Default;

mod F {
    use std::default::Default;
    use std::marker::PhantomData;

    pub struct Foo {
        pub bar: bool,
        phantom: PhantomData<()>,
    }

    impl Default for Foo {
        fn default() -> Foo {
            Foo {
                bar: false,
                phantom: PhantomData,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    F::Foo {
        bar: true,
        ..Default::default()
    };
}
```

This gives us the error:

```
error: field `phantom` of struct `F::Foo` is private [--explain E0451]
  --> <anon>:23:5
   |>
23 |>     F::Foo {
   |>     ^
```

Logically, I would argue that this should work, because we're only updating public fields, and it would be useful idiom. The alternative is to support something like:

```
Foo::new()
  .set_bar(true)
```

...which will get tedious with dozens of fields.

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Rename `phantom` to `__phantom`, make it public and `#[doc(hidden)]`. Live example: [`std::io::ErrorKind::__Nonexhaustive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/up/src/libstd/io/error.rs.html#162-168)

Comment: @mcarton Note that `std` is a little special in that it can declare the `__Nonexhaustive` variant to be unstable, so that callers literally cannot use it if they're on stable Rust. Library writers employing this same trick (which is something I definitely do) must rely on convention. (Which I don't think is a real problem in practice, I'm just being a pedant.)

Comment: @emk I was **just** learning about `PhantomData`. Thanks for this useful example!

Comment: @BurntSushi5 little ugly but `#[deprecated]` would work here if a warning is necessary.

Comment: @mcarton If you convert your comment into a top-level answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename `phantom` to `__phantom`, make it public and `#[doc(hidden)]`.

```
use std::default::Default;

mod foo {
    use std::default::Default;
    use std::marker::PhantomData;

    pub struct Foo {
        pub bar: bool,

        // We make this public but hide it from the docs, making
        // it private by convention.  If you use this, your
        // program may break even when semver otherwise says it
        // shouldn't.
        #[doc(hidden)]
        pub _phantom: PhantomData<()>,
    }

    impl Default for Foo {
        fn default() -> Foo {
            Foo {
                bar: false,
                _phantom: PhantomData,
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo::Foo {
        bar: true,
        ..Default::default()
    };
}
```

This is a not so uncommon pattern, live example: [`std::io::ErrorKind::__Nonexhaustive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/error.rs.html#177).

Sure, users won't have any warning or anything if they choose to use a `__named` field anyway, but the `__` makes the intent pretty clear. If a warning is required, `#[deprecated]` could be used.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted your answer because it directly answers the question, but the @Chris Emerson's answer provides a good alternative for higher-level APIs.

Answer (score 7):

The default field syntax doesn't work because you're still creating a new instance (even if you're trying to take some of the field values from another object).

> The alternative is to support something like:
>
> ```
> Foo::new()
>   .set_bar(true)
> ```
>
> ...which will get tedious with dozens of fields.

I'm not sure that even with many fields, this:

```
Foo::new()
   .set_bar(true)
   .set_foo(17)
   .set_splat("Boing")
```

is significantly more tedious than:

```
Foo {
   bar: true,
   foo: 17,
   splat: "Boing",
   ..Foo::default()
}
```

Alternatively, you could separate out the public fields into their own type:

```
pub struct FooPub {
    pub bar: bool,
    // other pub fields
}

pub struct Foo {
    pub bar: bool,
    // other pub fields
    // alternatively, group them: pub public: FooPub,

    foo: u64,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn new(init: FooPub) {
        Foo {
            bar: init.bar,
            // other pub fields
            // alternative: public: init

            // private fields
            foo: 17u64,
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then call it as:

```
Foo::new(FooPub{ bar: true })
```

or add a `fn FooPub::default()` to let you default some of the fields:

```
Foo::new(FooPub{ bar: true, ..FooPub::default()})
```

Comment: Thank you! These are all lovely solutions for a high-level API with relatively few fields. But in my case, I'm working with a much lower-level struct representing a 3rd-party file format deserialized with `serde`, and I need something that works with dozens of rarely-used fields, and which doesn't require me to split the struct in two. But your answer will help people with simpler problems. Thank you!